# socket.on() callback called twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, callback

Can anyone help me or explain to me why the callback of `socket.on` is being called twice.
I'm using `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` version `4.5.1`. I tried to put `socket.on` inside a `useEffect` but the invocation of callback is reduced to twice.
Here's the code:

client:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('ws://localhost:3001');

const Main = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>('');
  const [chat, setChat] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('recv_broadcast', message => { // this callback is being called twice
      console.log(message);
      setChat(state => [...state, message]);
    });
  }, []);

  const send = () => {
    setChat(state => [...state, message]);
    socket.emit('send_broadcast', message);
  }
...
```

server:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  console.log('Total client:', io.engine.clientsCount);

  socket.on('send_broadcast', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('recv_broadcast', message);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

React Strict mode runs some functions twice, meaning that it adds the `recv_broadcast` listener twice!

Go into your index.js file and remove the

```
<React.Strictmode> </React.Strictmode>
```

lines.

Hope this helps!